# SwiftUI Disabling recursion trigger logging when use Menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Hi everyone I'm using the **"Menu"** structure to display the possible choices to the user

```
public struct Menu <Label, Content>: Display where Label: Display, Content: Display
```

---

Everything seems to work with **SwiftUI** but I continue to receive alerts in the console that tell me this:

```
2021-09-30 20:55:40.032369+0200  [UILog] Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:] while no context menu is visible. This won't do anything.
2021-09-30 20:55:41.344436+0200  [UILog] Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:] while no context menu is visible. This won't do anything.
2021-09-30 20:55:41.414976+0200  [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x10401dc00 Disabling recursion trigger logging
2021-09-30 20:55:41.417708+0200  [UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x10401dc00 Disabling recursion trigger logging
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

This is my code for the Menu

```
private var months: [Date] {
    calendar.createDate(
        interval: calendar.dateInterval(of: .year, for: Date())
              matching: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
           )
       }

     
var body: some View {
    
      Menu("Options") {
          ForEach(months, id:\.self) { month 
             Button("\(DateFormatter(format: "MMMM").string(from: month))"){
                        selectedDate = month }
                }
            }
      }
```

Comment: Says it's bug from apple
https://twitter.com/caughtinflux/status/1439276097464528896?s=21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Minho shared it's seems to be a simple debug / diagnostic left by a dev.

Fortunately for us they used `Os.Log` which we should all use, correctly like it is done here.

Using the console we can identify the subsystem and category of the messages

[console.app logs of related error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZq1f.png)

We can then tell `Os.Log` to ignore the related `subsystem` and `Category`
With `subsystem: com.apple.UIKit` and `category: UICollectionViewRecursion`

This give us the following commands, the first for system (device), the second for the booted simulator.

```
// Disable forgotten 'UICollectionViewRecursion' debug messages, see.
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397650/swiftui-disabling-recursion-trigger-logging-when-use-menu
// https://twitter.com/caughtinflux/status/1439276097464528896?s=21
sudo log config --mode "level:off" --subsystem com.apple.UIKit --category UICollectionViewRecursion
xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode "level:off" --subsystem com.apple.UIKit --category UICollectionViewRecursion
```

Hope this helps and again please use `Os.Log` in your projects.